# PLSQL ignore compilation error which is not an error

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, compiler-warnings

I came accross interesting error where I am not sure about best way how to fix it. Given following block:

```
    DECLARE
      v_column_exists number := 0;  
      host_column_exists number := 0;
      i number;
    BEGIN
      Select count(*) into v_column_exists from user_tab_cols where column_name = 'CONNECTIONDESCRIPTION' and table_name = 'NODES';

      if (v_column_exists = 1) then
        Select count(*) into host_column_exists from user_tab_cols where column_name = 'HOST' and table_name = 'NODES';

        if (host_column_exists = 0) then
          execute immediate 'alter table NODES add (Host varchar2(255))';
          for item in (select connectiondescription, code from nodes) loop
            ... LOOP STUFF ...
          end loop;
        end if;
      end if;
    END;
```

I get following result:

> PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "CONNECTIONDESCRIPTION": invalid identifier
>   ORA-06550: line 40, column 20: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   ORA-06550: line 41, column 20: PLS-00364: loop index variable 'ITEM'
>   use is invalid

any ideas how to get rid of this error? Problem is occuring when column `NODES.CONNECTIONDESCRIPTION` is not present in database, however in such case for loop won't execute in runtime. I would need to disable these errors, but haven't found any way to do it. I have tried using `ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS='DISABLE:00904'`, but it had no effect.

Thanks

Comment: Dynamic query? you've got already one execute immediate so why not add another one. Or conditional compilation, if it is possible in you case

Comment: Instead of disabling the error, why don't you make sure that the column is actually in the table or that you have explicit SELECT grant over that table?

Comment: @micklesh thanks for reply, I have already found a way which is in fact same as your suggestion. Another dynamic query which bulk collects to an array and then looping through the array

Comment: @ruudvan: it is possible workaround, but adding column which you need to handle just to get rid of compilation error does not seem like correct practice

Comment: I see what you mean now. The question was slightly ambiguous. My mistake. Dynamic query is definitely what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Correct approach was to use another dynamic query which bulk collects items to an array and then loop through this array.